# Replace WRITE statement with assignment loop

Tags: io, fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I need to store in a variable the values of a WRITE with a implicit loop but cannot grasp how the loop should be constructed.

The variable is a `COMPLEX*16` with dimensions `(2, 9, 1, 3, 3)`

```
WRITE(UNIT, 2) (SIGATool(2, 1, IREC, IT, 3), IT = 1, MAXPOL), &
                    (SIGATool(2, 2, IREC, IT, 3), IT = 1, MAXPOL), &   
                    (SIGATool(2, 3, IREC, IT, 3), IT = 1, MAXPOL), &
                    ((((SIGATool(IFREQ, IARRAY, IREC, IT, IR), IR = 1, MAXPOL), IT = 1, MAXPOL), &
                     IFREQ = 1, NFREQ), IARRAY = 4, NARRAY)
2    FORMAT(<234>E25.15)
```

where

```
IREC = 1, NARRAY = 9, IFREQ = 3, MAXPOL = 3
```

In other words: I am looking for a way that instead of writing to a file puts the result in a 1D array output, from the format statement it looks like having  117 complex numbers, but how do I loop it the same way the WRITE statement is doing ??

Comment: What are "the values of WRITE"? I tried to make your question more clear but I did not understand some parts very well.

Comment: @anon, please take more care when editing code.  The line `IREC = 1, NARRAY = 9, IFREQ = 3, MAXPOL = 3`, although poorly formatted, is not a valid line of Fortran and doesn't belong in the formatted code block.

Comment: I find loops around the write are easier then part of the write.

Comment: Reading this again, I perhaps understand.  You want a one-dimensional array where the elements in order are the same as would appear from that output statement?  If so, you can just make the output list into [an array constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/996/arrays/6858/array-constructors), keeping the implied-do loops.

Comment: @francescalus that solved - wasnt aware of the initialization from 2003 with implicit do-loop, many thanks! If you create a answer I will accept it.

Comment: I may be able to properly answer later on, when I'm not on a train.

Comment: Or maybe use PACK ?